# Mvc HttpPostedFileBase returns null

Tags: asp.net-mvc, file-upload, null, return

lately i was trying to handle HttpPostedFileBase returns null issue, but i cannot really figure it out why my input file returns null although i've researched all the similiar questions to get to know about the problem in the site.My sutiation is  i need to have four input file because i need four different documents other than each other.

here is part of the view:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Create", "MyController", FormMethod.Post, new { enctype ="multipart/form-data" }))
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()

<div style="padding-left: 32px;">
    @Html.ValidationSummary(true)
    @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.Id)
<table>
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td style="width: 132px;"><div><b>...</b></div></td>
                <td style="width:250px;">
                    <input type="file" name="upload1" id="upload1" class="formin" />
                    <input type="hidden" name="UploadType1" id="UploadType1" value="@Request.QueryString["UploadType"]" />
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td style="width: 132px;"><div><b>...</b></div></td>
                <td style="width:250px;">
                    <input type="file" name="upload2" id="upload2" class="formin" />
                    <input type="hidden" name="UploadType2" id="UploadType2" value="@Request.QueryString["UploadType"]" />
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td style="width: 132px;"><div><b>...</b></div></td>
                <td style="width:250px;">
                    <input type="file" name="upload3" id="upload3" class="formin" />
                    <input type="hidden" name="UploadType3" id="UploadType3" value="@Request.QueryString["UploadType"]" />
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td style="width: 132px;"><div><b>...</b></div></td>
                <td style="width:250px;">
                    <input type="file" name="upload4" id="upload4" class="formin" />
                    <input type="hidden" name="UploadType4" id="UploadType4" value="@Request.QueryString["UploadType"]" />
                </td>
            </tr>

        </tbody>
    </table>
    <table>
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td style="width:220px;"><div><b></b></div></td>
                <td> <input type="submit" name="submit" value="GÖNDER" class="formbutton" style="font-size: 14px;background:maroon;color:white;"></td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
```

here is my controller:

```
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Create(HttpPostedFileBase upload1, HttpPostedFileBase upload2, HttpPostedFileBase upload3, HttpPostedFileBase upload4, string UploadType1, string UploadType2, string UploadType3, string UploadType4)
    {
     List<Ek> eks = new List<Ek>();


            if (upload1!=null && upload1.ContentLength > 0)
            {
                var upload1Name= Path.GetFileName(upload1Name.FileName);
                var path1 = Path.Combine(Server.MapPath("~/Documents/.../upload1"), PhotoName);
                upload1.SaveAs(path1);


                Ek e1 = new Ek { 
                UploadType = GetTypeEnum(UploadType1),
                UploadPath = "/Documents/.../.../" + upload1Name
                };
                eks.Add(e1);
            }

            if (upload2!= null && upload2.ContentLength > 0)
            {
                var upload2Name = Path.GetFileName(upload2.FileName);
                var path2 = Path.Combine(Server.MapPath("~/Documents/.../..."), upload2Name);
                upload2.SaveAs(path2);

                Ek e2 = new Ek
                {
                    UploadType = GetTypeEnum(UploadType1),
                    UploadPath = "/Documents/.../.../" + upload2Name 
                };
                eks.Add(e2);
            }

            if (upload3!= null && upload3.ContentLength > 0)
            {
                var upload3Name = Path.GetFileName(upload3.FileName);
                var path3 = Path.Combine(Server.MapPath("~/Documents/.../..."), upload3Name );
                upload3.SaveAs(path3);

                Ek e3 = new Ek
                {
                    UploadType = GetTypeEnum(UploadType1),
                    UploadPath = "/Documents/.../" + upload3Name 
                };

                eks.Add(e3);
            }

            if (upload4!= null && upload4.ContentLength > 0)
            {
                var upload4Name = Path.GetFileName(upload4.FileName);
                var path4 = Path.Combine(Server.MapPath("~/Documents/.../"), upload4Name);
                languagepoint.SaveAs(path4);

                Ek e4 = new Ek
                {
                    UploadType = GetTypeEnum(UploadType1),
                    UploadPath = "/Documents/.../" + upload4Name 
                };

                eks.Add(e4);

            }
        //some stuff here
        return RedirectToAction("Success");
    }

    return View(myview);
   }
    private UploadType GetTypeEnum(string UploadType1)
    {

        Models.UploadType uType= UploadType.MyType;
        switch (UploadType1)
        {
            case "MyType":
            uType = UploadType.MyType;
                break;
                   case "MyType1":
            uType = UploadType.MyType1;
                break;
                   case "MyType2":
            uType = UploadType.MyType2;
                break;
                   case "MyType3":
            uType = UploadType.MyType3;
                break;
            default:
                break;
        }
        return uType;
    }
```

and finally here is my modal:

```
    public partial class MyMainClass
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public virtual IList<Ek> Ek { get; set; }

}
    public partial class Ek
{
    public int ID { get; set; }

    public UploadType UploadType { get; set; }
    public string UploadPath { get; set; }
}

public enum UploadType
{
    MyType= 0,
    MyType1= 1,
    MyType2= 2,
    MyType3= 3
}
```

Thank you for all the answers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just Correct Your HttpPost Controller as :

```
 [HttpPost]
 public ActionResult Create(IEnumerable<HttpPostedFileBase> files)
 {
   if (files.Count() > 0)  // display no of files uploaded
   if (files.Any())  // display true
   if (files.First() == null)  // display "first null"

   return View();
 }
```

**Because you are uploading more than one file from view so you have to use IEnumerable of HttpPostedFileBase and write HttpPost attribute on Create action because it is accepting your POST Request.**

Comment: But in my model it's specified as IList, so should i change it to IEnumerable?

Comment: @user3055125...you don't have to change anything just update your code as i answered and see with by applying breakpoint that files in IEnumerable<HttpPostedFileBase> files have values or not..

Comment: the problem is, each uploadtype other than eachother should upload to different folders but if i let them to upload into the same folder later on i might have difficulties making them seperate one by one im looking for another solution thanks for helping if cannot manage what i want exactly ill try your approach.

Comment: thanks a lot and if u have an approach for my scenario do not hesitate to share your idea :)

Comment: @user3055125...okk...don't worry

Comment: now i am able to upload four of them but at this moment having another exception like "An object with the same key already exists in the ObjectStateManager. The ObjectStateManager cannot track multiple objects with the same key." it's because of my "ek" field that im trying to track the types of "ek" so that i can easily distinguish them.

Comment: When i make it as IEnumerable the table of Ek was gone from the database after migration, so can i make it as ICollection? or if IEnumerable needed how to not to let code first to not to remove the ek table and write on it some informations?

Comment: @user3055125....this should not happen... why table gone from database just refresh your database and see.. i think there is problem somewhere else just check....

Comment: it's because of IEnumerable as i guess i'have reverted the last migration and made the field back as IList then migrate it and ek table showed up and after again i've changed it to IEnumerable and migrate it too then ek table disappeared for the second time..

Comment: strange... then keep it as ilist and see on httppost that ienumerable files contains file or not... if so then your problem will be solved....